# how can finish old activites after paying activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

in my app there are 
activities :
Login > search > search result list > item details > pay > my item details

when i'm in 'search result list' and click back  it will back to 'search' same in item details
it will back to search result list

how can finish many old activites after paying proccess ??

Answer (score 1):

use can use this

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
 if(resultCode==0){
 finish(); 
}
else{
 }
}
```

and you use `setResult(0);` when you destory the activity you in it

and there is another solution  when you in first activity finish it  after you call the startAcitivty
for second activity

Answer (score 0):

To Finish an Activity I'm using this code:

```
public void AppExit(){
this.finish();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intetn.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
}

or kill Process with this code:

int pid = android.as.Process.myPid();
android.os.Process.KillProcess(pid);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this. When you are going to start an intent , call `finish()` method like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,abc.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Comment: i want to kill old parent activites , your code keep old activites stopped then i can return to it :(